# Why does DSB not flush the cache?

Tags: caching, arm, cpu-cache, dma, memory-barriers

I'm debugging an HTTP server on STM32H725VG  using LWIP and HAL drivers, all initially generated by STM32CubeMX. The problem is that in some cases data sent via `HAL_ETH_Transmit` have some octets replaced by 0x00, and this corrupted content successfully gets to the client.

I've checked that the data in the buffers passed as arguments into `HAL_ETH_Transmit` are intact both before and after the call to this function. So, apparently, the corruption occurs on transfer from the RAM to the MAC, because the checksum is calculated on the corrupted data. So I supposed that the problem may be due to interaction between cache and DMA. I've tried disabling D-cache, and then the corruption doesn't occur.

Then I thought that I should just use `__DSB()` instruction that should write the cached data into the RAM. After enabling D-cache back, I added `__DSB()` right before the call to `HAL_ETH_Transmit` (which is inside `low_level_output` function generated by STM32CubeMX), and... nothing happened: the data are still corrupted.

Then, after some experimentation I found that `SCB_CleanDCache()` call after (or instead of) `__DSB()` fixes the problem.

This makes me wonder. The description of `DSB` instruction is [as follows](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/miscellaneous-instructions/dmb--dsb--and-isb):

> Data Synchronization Barrier acts as a special kind of memory barrier. No instruction in program order after this instruction executes until this instruction completes. This instruction completes when:
>
> - All explicit memory accesses before this instruction complete.
> - All Cache, Branch predictor and TLB maintenance operations before this instruction complete.

And the [description of `SCB_DisableDCache`](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__Dcache__functions__m7.html#gafe64b44d1a61483a947e44a77a9d3287) has the following note about `SCB_CleanDCache`:

> When disabling the data cache, you must clean (`SCB_CleanDCache`) the entire cache to ensure that any dirty data is flushed to external memory.

Why doesn't the `DSB` flush the cache if it's supposed to be complete when "all explicit memory accesses" complete, which seems to include flushing of caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dsb ish` works as a memory barrier for inter-thread memory order; it just orders the current CPU's access to coherent cache.  You wouldn't expect `dsb ish` to flush any cache because that's not required for visibility within the same inner-shareable cache-coherency domain.  Like it says in the manual you quoted, it finishes memory operations.

Cacheable memory operations on write-back cache only update cache; waiting for them to finish doesn't imply flushing the cache.

Your ARM system I think has multiple coherency domains for microcontroller vs. DSP?  Does your `__DSB` intrinsic compile to a `dsb sy` instruction?  Assuming that doesn't flush cache, what they mean is presumably that it orders memory / cache operations including explicit flushes, which are still necessary.

Comment: Yes, it compiles to `dsb sy` (the definition of the macro spells it as `dsb 0xF`).

Comment: @Ruslan: ok, still, I think that just means make sure any previous memory operation is done, but doesn't retroactively make it uncacheable.  Note that some compilers (like GCC) previously used `dmb sy` instead of `ish`for `std::atomic` code, so making `dmb sy` flush cache would be a performance disaster if running code compiled that way which happened to use some atomic ref-counting or something that might happen even in a binary that didn't start multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put my money on performance.

Flushing cache means to write data from cache to memory. Memory access is slow.

L1 cache size (assuming ARM Cortex-A9) is 32KB. You don't want to move a whole 32KB from cache into memory for no reason. There might be L2 cache which is easily 512KB-1MB (could be even more). You really don't want to move a whole L2 either.

As a matter of fact your whole DMA transfer might be smaller than size of caches. There is simply no justification to do that.